# Questions on using ttk.Style()?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

To make available an instance of the ttk.Style() class, it was illustrated  in this [tkinter guide](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-theme-layer.html) that the syntax is:

```
import ttk
s=ttk.Style()
```

When typing these command in IDLE, I noticed that ttk.Style() actually has a predefined argument, i.e.

```
s=ttk.Style(master=None)
```

I have written the following test script:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, style='App.TFrame', relief=tk.SUNKEN,
                           border=10)
        self.parent = parent
        self.__createStyle()
        self.__createWidgets()

    def __createStyle(self):
        self.s = ttk.Style()
        self.s.configure('.', background='orange', border=100)
        self.s.configure('App.TFrame', background='yellow')
        self.s.configure('Btn.TButton', background='light blue', border=10)

    def __createWidgets(self):
        self._label = ttk.Label(self.parent, text='Label packed in root.')
        self._label.pack()
        self._btn = ttk.Button(self, style='Btn.TButton', command=self.__click,
            text='Button packed inside self or class App, which is a ttk.Frame')
        self._btn.pack()

    def __click(self):
        return print('Left Button Clicked!')



class myWidget(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, style='my.TFrame', relief=tk.GROOVE,
                           border=10)
        self.parent = parent
        self.__createStyle()
        self.__createWidgets()

    def __createStyle(self):
        self.s = ttk.Style()
        self.s.configure('my.TFrame', background='purple')
        self.s.configure('my.TLabel', background='pink', border=10)
        self.s.configure('my.TEntry', foreground='red', border=10)

    def __createWidgets(self):
        self._label = ttk.Label(self, style='my.TLabel',
            text='myWidget Label packed in self or class myWidget, which is a ttk.Frame.')

        self._label.pack()
        self._entry = ttk.Entry(self, style='my.TEntry')
        self._entry.pack()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Test Style')
    root.geometry('500x150')
    a = App(root)
    a.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
    b = myWidget(a)
    b.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

**Question 1:** When do I need to declare the `master` arguement in `ttk.Style()`? E.g. in the above script, if I write `self.s = ttk.Style()` and `self.s = ttk.Style(master=self.parent)` in `class myWidget`, I get the same result (see Fig1).

**Question 2:** Is there a need to prefix `s=ttk.Style()` with `self`? I get the same result as shown in Fig1 with and without the `self` prefix.

**Question 3:** If I rename `'my.TFrame'` in class myWidget as `'App.TFrame'`(this name was used in `class App`), the background colour of the `class App` changed to purple color too (same color as `class myWidget`. Why did this happened given that variable name in different classes are unique?

**Question 4:** The names `'App.TFrame'` and `'my.TFrame'` were called before it was declared. Why did python or tkinter not complain or give an  error but allowed the script to execute?

[image: Fig1]

**Figure 1**

[image: Fig2]

**Figure 2**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When do I need to declare the `master` arguement in `ttk.Style()`?

Probably never, except the case when `tkinter` doesnt support the `default root`. When you pass `None` as the master, the master becomes the current `root` instance of `Tk` class.

The main purpose of the `master` (`root` or any `tk`-widget) is to delegate instance of `tk` to the `Style`, so that the `Style` could be able to execute `Tcl`-related commands.

No more, no less.

---

> Is there a need to prefix `s=ttk.Style()` with `self`?

It depends on your requirements. In context of your code -  `self` is meaningless, because you're setting up styles in a scope of the `__createStyle` function.

Otherwise, if you wish to keep the reference, it makes sense to prefix with `self.`

---

> If I rename `my.TFrame` in class myWidget as `App.TFrame`(this name was used in `class App`), the background colour of the `class App` changed to purple color too (same color as `class myWidget`. Why did this happened given that variable name in different classes are unique?

Because both of classes share the same frame style, hence the same color. Created style is a global thing, it can be chaged at runtime, and all the relevant widgets will react to these chages.

---

> The names `App.TFrame` and `my.TFrame` were called before it was declared. Why did python or tkinter not complain or give an error but allowed the script to execute?

Why you think they should? When you pass something like `<any_sensible_name>.<any_relevant_and_existing_basestyle>`, `ttk` knows that you want a variation of a base style, so it's implicitly creates one, which inherits all base properties.

Try that trick with something more meaningless, like your current style name without dot (`ttk.Frame.__init__(..., style='AppTFrame', ...)`), which gives you the desired error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: Layout AppTFrame not found
```

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that `ttk_frame_widget.winfo_class()` returns `'TFrame'`.

Comment: Can u elaborate _"When you pass None as the master, the master becomes the current root instance of Tk class."_ using my script? For `class App`, I read `self.s = ttk.Style()` as `ttk.Frame.s` (or `a.s`) is `ttk.Style`. According to `ttk.py`, `ttk.Style()` is to define `self.tk = self.master.tk` where `self.master` is either `tkinter._default_root` or `tkinter.Tk()`. I think `tkinter.Tk()` will create a new root, while `tkinter._default_root` will refer to the root of `a` which is also tkinter.Tk(). For `class myWidget`, it's master is `a` which is a `class App`. So what happens here?

Comment: @Sun Bear, `ttk.Style().master` could be an anything (Tk, Toplevel, Frame,  any widget), that holds reference to `tk`. In your case, you implicitly pass `None` as the `master`, so `master` becomes `tkinter._default_root`, which is your `root`. This easy to check via `print(root is tk._default_root)`. That's it, there's no room for a new instance of `Tk`.

Answer (score 3):

Only a partial Answer, but I suppose @Bryan Oakley will entlighten us sooner or later.

**Question 3:**
If you use "App.TFrame" instead of "my.TFrame" inside your MyWidget Class, you override the predefined style properties.

*Short example:*
If you style `"TFrame"`, all `"TFrame"`( == Tkinter.Frame/ttk.Frame ) instances will be affected.
This is also sometimes referred to as "root-Style".
If you define another `"somename.TFrame"` and set it for one Object of type frame, it will be styles according `"somename.TFrame"`.

**Question 4:**
The lookup names only override default styles.
 As long as they have no properties, they do not override a thing.
This "assignment" results in a tcl call and has no specific error handling inside the Tkinter / ttk Sources (used in BaseWidget class).

I can only tell that tcl does not throw an error here but I am not a tcl expert myself.

I hope this at least helps a bit.